# Google Cloud Messaging - object field data is null on response

Tags: browser, google-cloud-messaging, cloud, messaging

How to get data (payload?) from GCM in browser client? I get push-notification and all. In response from GCM, I get an empty objet field data. I want to send push notification with message by client in a browser. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, for downstream messaging, GCM provides two types of **payload**: notification and data. In Data payload you need to include the developer’s custom key/value pairs only, and the client app must handle the message.

You can read the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#payload) about data in the message payload.

I will suggest you to read this documentation [Implementing GCM Client on Chrome](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client) to know more information in setting up the GCM in the browser client.

Make sure that the enable API that you use is **"Google Cloud Messaging for Android"**. Because **"Google Cloud Messaging for Android"** will give you access to the normal GCM API. **"Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome"** won’t (it’s used for Chrome Apps in the Chrome Web Store).

You can also check this [tutorial](http://hayageek.com/google-cloud-messaging-for-chrome/) for more information and sample code.

Comment: Not working, with using in browser
   
Request, my body data is null:
`{
    "registration_ids":["XXX"], 
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "XXX",
      "title" : "XXX",
      "icon" : "XXX"
    },
    "content_available":true,
    "collapse_key": "XXX"
}`

Service-worker with not writting install and activate: 
`self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(
            'XXX', {
                body: 'XXX',
                icon: 'XXX'
            }
        )
    );
});`